# trying to plot a beautiful image using the dataset

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot an image something similar to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3zOb.png) by using the data provided here [data](https://transfer.pcloud.com/download.html?code=5ZTvhsVZD5tA3pjvqSLZri6IZ8pdgP4189iXHjBI0ePghljTWf7jX)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker

inp_data=np.loadtxt("data")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.5, 12.0))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.55, 0.2, 0.04])
plt.setp(ax1.spines.values(), linewidth=0.5)
ax1.minorticks_on()
ax1.imshow(inp_data,aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Here problem is that, the image is going blank even after the adjustment of vmin and vmax.
I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem and help me plotting a beautiful plot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `fig` and `ax1` in your code? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CreepyRaccoon I updated the code, please have a look.Thanks.

Comment: From [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html) doc: `vmin, vmax`: "This parameter is ignored if X is RGB(A)" | `X`: "(M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int)". So you need to scale the data **before** using `imshow`

Comment: @paime can you please let me know how to do in my provided data sets

Comment: Look at formulas here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html